# How to detect if a player is looking at a type of entity

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm planning on creating a "weeping angel" scene like  from *Doctor Who*. I already have figured out how to do the "move when the lights are out" part (`{noAI:1b}` set when the lights are on, set off when lights are off). But I want to know if you can set it so that they also stop moving if they are in your FOV (field of view) when the lights are on, maybe just if you are looking at them. I'm planning on using skeletons, unless you can detect when an Enderman gets mad because a player is looking at it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

Actually yes, you can use the `/testfor @e[e=tag] r=3` command. I believe that is the command that will tell you when something is within a certain distance of an entity. The sight detection is very tricky but I will get back to you if that method does not work for you.
ALSO, you must put the entity tag for the enderman in the brackets after the `e=`.

Comment: Success! Lookup player rotation detection and click on the video that has the interlocking blue and red circles. The /testfor @e command should still work